# Store Username and Password securely for xfreerdp

Tags: linux, security, xfreerdp

I am xfreerdp to login to my other pcs. I am storing the connection on bash file,

> xfreerdp /multimon /u:{username} /v:{ip:port} /p:{password}
> -d:{domain}  /f /floatbar /multitransport /network:auto

I click on them when I want to connect. But the issue is anyone with access to this machine will get the username and password of my other machines, what is the proper way to store and execute such files.

I am relatively new to Linux, so please consider that.

Answer (score 1):

When passing in `/from-stdin` as an argument you can pipe your password to `xfreerdp`.

> `echo "your_password"| xfreerdp /v:host /network:auto /u:user /from-stdin`

Without echoing your password, `xfreerdp` will ask you for your password.
So you could write your password to file and echo it out every time.

> `echo "password" > password_file.txt`

> `cat passfile.txt | xfreerdp /v:host/network:auto /u:user /from-stdin`

If you want to shorten this, you could write this as an alias to your bashrc.

> `echo "alias connect_to_my_host='cat /path/to/passfile.txt | xfreerdp /v:host/network:auto /u:user /from-stdin'" >> ~/.bashrc`

I do **not recommend** doing that (saving passwords unencrypted is always a bad idea)! A safer way is to use an rdp-client like [remmina](https://remmina.org/) to handle your rdp connections. Remmina will encrypt your passwords to `~/.config/remmina/remmina.pref.

Comment: remmina was my first choice but it does not support multimonitor